# Where to declare onOptionsItemSelected for global use?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android development.

In my `MainActivity.java` file, I've declared an `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu)` method that allows the user to jump between the current `MainActivity.java` page and another page I created called `Settings.java`.

When the user goes to the `Settings.java` page, and they click on the `Home` option from the menu, nothing happens. I know this is because the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu)` is only defined in the `MainActivity.java` class and not in the `Settings.java` class.

I'm overcoming this right now by copying the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu)` from `MainActivity.java` into `Settings.java`. But this is very redundant.

Where should I be declaring methods that could be reused in different classes?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                showMsg("Settings Clicked");
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.action_home:
                showMsg("Home clicked");
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void showMsg(String msg) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**Settings.java**

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.action_home:
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an Activity called `BaseActivity` that has your common `onOptionsItemSelected()` code then extend this class to create `MainActivity` and `Settings` both of these classes will use the `super` class' (i.e. `BaseActivity`'s) `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Another approach is to switch to Fragments, since Fragments use the host Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()` as well as their own.  Both of these tactics allow you to use "centralized" code and not have to maintain multiple "cut and paste" copies.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the `BaseActivity` option. I'll look into Fragments in the near future.